# Apps Script publish a web app when not the owner of the file

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet which is tied into a lot of other sheets and API functionality so copying it is not an attractive option. Currently I have reached google quota limits using my private gmail account so I set up a paid Gsuite account which gives me greater quota. My intention is that the scripts on the sheet should run through the new account to take advantage of the quota. I cannot publish the web app to run under other users' accounts because of another limitation.

However when I tried to publish a web app under the new Gsuite account it hung and said "collecting data." Further reading indicated that to publish a web app you may need to be the owner of the spreadsheet. So I tried to transfer ownership of the spreadsheet from my personal gmail account to the Gsuite account but I was met with the message that ownership cannot be transferred to another domain.

So my question is if there is anything I can do to publish the web app under the new Gsuite account  or if copying the file is the only way to go.

Comment: Setup a team drive between you GSuite Account and your Old Account.  Give both accounts full access and move the file to the drive from your old account and take it off on your new account and magically it becomes yours.  Also remove any sharings before you do this.  I do this all of the time on my G-Suite business account.

Comment: Thanks Cooper, this worked. Just a note for anyone who wants to do this, you need Gsuite for Business, not Gsuite Basic.